# What pressure sensor and how should it be installed on to the medical ventilator to get the pressure flow graph?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, sensors, medical-devices

I'm currently building a project named camshaft mechanism medical ventilator. One of the objective of my project is to get the pressure flow graph from my user. I succesfully build my camshaft. However, i stucked on pressure related problems even tho i searched it for more than 1 weeks.

1. What are the pressure sensor that i should use.
   ( there's is alot of pressure sensor as some websites says mems pressure suit the most some says barometric pressure, and im totally confused.)
2. How should it be installed so that i can measure my pressure data.
   (I don't see any source or material that i can refer so that i can understand the mechanism)

The pressure flow graph is around 1:42 in the link below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgAR4yWDsg0&t=73s

Thank you!

Comment: Examples of medical sensors:
https://allsensors.com/company/pressure-sensors-for-ventilators
https://superiorsensors.com/pressure-sensors/spirometry/
It should be installed in a place, where you need to measure pressure. Precautions against water condensate should be taken. And medical certification, of course.

Comment: consider putting all the images in your question and not use links to other sites (they might become obsolete without warning).